# How do I match everything in this string except .json at the end?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given this string

```
 "www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123.json"
```

I'm trying to match everything in here except the last ".json" part.  In other words, I want a regex that will do the following:

```
 sum_regex.match("www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123.json")
 => "www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123"
```

Is this possible with just regex?

Comment: When you ask a question asking for code, you need to show what you've tried and explain why it didn't work for you. See #3 in the "[on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp)

```
"www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123.json".chomp( ".json" )
#> "www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123"
```

Comment: You can also combine chomp with other methods/functions/commands within the ruby script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
t = 'www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123.json'
t.match( /^(.*)\.json$/ )[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead that is only a test and that is not a part of the final result:

```
sum_regex.match("www\.monkeysports\.com%2Fcontent%2F123(?=\.json\z)")
```

`(?=...)` the lookahead assertion *(i.e. followed by)*

`\z` the end of the string anchor

Notice: don't forget to escape the dot that is a special character.

Comment: You can use the greediness of `.*` to consume the whole string, then make the regex engine back up until it finds a dot: `/ (.*) [.] /xm`...but of course this is not a job for regexes.

Comment: @7stud: Yes, it's indeed possible (and shorter), but it is probably more slow due to the backtracking and it doesn't check if the string ends with `.json`. A split/join approach can be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to tell the Regular Expression engine to select what you want, and to exclude what you don't want:

```
"www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123.json"[/^(.+)\.json/, 1] # => "www.monkeysports.com%2Fcontent%2F123"
```

This works because:

- [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) allows us to pass in a regular expression, which it then applies to the string.
- The pattern `/^(.+)\.json/` basically says, "start at the beginning of the string, and select everything until ".json" is found.
- In `[/^(.+)\.json/, 1]`, the ", 1" means return the captured part of the string. In other words, return what was found that matched the part inside the parenthesis. This is what the [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) documentation means by "`str[regexp, capture]`".